# GNU parallel combination of array arguments?

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I have a bash function:

```
println(){echo "$1" "$2" "$3"}
```

and

```
export -f println
```

I want to use GNU parallel to run println. The command should take inputs of the following arrays:

```
a1=(a b c) 

a2=(x y)

a3=(z1 z2)
```

It should output the follows:

```
   a x a3
   a y a3
   b x a3
   b y a3
   c x a3
   c y a3
```

Which command can do that? I expect the command like:

```
 parallel ... println ... a1 ... a2 .... a3
```

Thank you!

Comment: `a x a3
   a y a3` Don't you want `z1` `z2` ?

Comment: No, I take a1, a2 as data, a3 as argument to println.

Answer (score 5):

Just put `:::` in between:

```
$ parallel println ::: "${a1[@]}" ::: "${a2[@]}" ::: "${a3[@]}"
a y z1
a x z1
a y z2
a x z2
b x z2
b x z1
b y z2
b y z1
c x z2
c x z1
c y z1
c y z2
```

The `println(){echo "$1" "$2" "$3"}` is invalid, it needs to be `println(){ echo "$1" "$2" "$3"; }`.

Comment: Thank, great! Let me slightly adpat to:  parallel println ::: "${a1[@]}" ::: "${a2[@]}" ::: "$a3". If one want to add more arguments to println,  parallel println $arg1 $arg2 ... $argn ::: "${a1[@]}" ::: "${a2[@]}" ::: "$a3" works; otherwise, the first ::: can be removed?

Comment: @lidingxu Correct.

Answer (score 1):

Can be applied *Brace Expansion* in bash with variable `IFS`

```bsh
(IFS=,; eval printf %s "{${a1[*]}}\ {${a2[*]}}\ {${a3[*]}}\$'\n'")
```

```
a x z1
a x z2
a y z1
a y z2
b x z1
b x z2
b y z1
b y z2
c x z1
c x z2
c y z1
c y z2
```

`(...)` - We execute in a subshell so as not to return the value to the `IFS` variable.

Or exactly like in your example:

```bsh
(IFS=,; eval printf %s "{${a1[*]}}\ {${a2[*]}}\ a3\$'\n'")
a x a3
a y a3
b x a3
b y a3
c x a3
c y a3
```

Comment: Ok, but, there is no parallel.

Comment: Yes, then in your example the function is clearly superfluous `parallel echo ::: ${a1[@]} ::: ${a2[2]} ::: ${a3[@]}`